Entire home WAN connection drops during peak use
My entire house's internet connection drops randomly, but MUCH more likely when many online multiplayer games are being played. What sort of information should I capture about my network and the devices on it, so that I might be able to find large problems with things connected to my home network?
I live in a house with many internet consumers. When many people are playing online games, especially when one or more of those people are playing Overwatch 2, the houses entire internet connection drops.
Pinging out from my router during this time results in complete timeouts. I upgraded our internet connection recently and the problem had seemed to get better, though the ISP did maintenance in our neighborhood soon after I kept calling them to tell them my connection was dropping dead. I also have replaced or upgraded nearly every piece of network hardware since then. The most devices any single ethernet cable might be providing connectivity for is like 10. I own every network device except for the modem.
I have been setting up a home lab but I have very few services running right now, and none of them were around for similar WAN connectivity failures in the past.
So again, while I would love any help with figuring this out, I most want to know:
What sort of information should I capture about my network and the devices on it, so that I might be able to find large problems with things connected to my home network? I work in IT/DevOps but I don't really deal with network infrastructure type problems. I am already planning to set up some metric tracking (ex. Grafana/Influx/Loki) so I think what I really need to know is what metrics I need to make sure to collect, and what type of information I can use to help find out if something in/about my network is the cause or can I blame the ISP again? Without evidence I am ultimately just guessing.
